# Where does information in BackBone go?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

When a `save`, or `create` is tossed towards the server, the server responds with a new randomly created object. The object can be one of many different Classes, and Backbone responds to these differentiating objects and loads a relative view.

I can only seem to figure this logic out on bootstrap, as no view has been loaded yet, so I can based on what information I am randomly receiving from the server, bootstrap and navigate to that specific route.

However, I am stuck on trying to figure out how to do this when I save an object, and receive my return data.

Here's my code broken down.

**The information is saved.**

```
@model.save(@model.toJSON(),
```

**I have a listenener waiting for this save :**

```
constructor: (options) ->
  super(options)
  @model.bind 'change:verb', _.chooser, options
```

**_.maestra_chooser is a mixin I have in a utility belt  :**

```
_.mixin
  _chooser : (item) =>
    console.log item
```

Something to note here. The variable `item` is unfortunately, the same `@model` that was just saved. No new data there.

What I'm hoping for `item` to be is the new variable data from the server, so that I can take that data, see what kind of data it is, and then route to the relevant view.

This is where I believe I'm also making an architecturally unsound idea. But for reasons I don't understand enough to explain.

Does anyone know *where* I can access the return data from the server and appropriately navigate my app to that respective route?

**Additional Information**

This is how I bootstrap it appropriately :

```
window.router = new Project.Routers.QuestionsRouter(
{
  words: #{ @words.to_json.html_safe }  
});

Backbone.history.start();

router.navigate("#{@words.kind_of?(Array) ? "bar" : "foo"}", {trigger: true, replace: true})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding to the model's `sync` event, rather than the `change` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is only ever going to give you the model and the value that changed...

You can pass a success callback to your save:

```
@model.save(@model.toJSON(), success: (model, resp) ->
    # do whatever with resp
)
```

where `resp` will contain the raw response from the server and `model` will contain the server side state of your model.

You can also bind to your model's sync event as mentioned in the comments:

```
@model.bind 'sync', _.masetra_chooser, options
```

the `sync` callback is called with arguments: model, resp and options where options is the set of options passed to `save`.
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/9a12b7640f07839134e979b66df658b70e6e4fe9/backbone.js#L383

Not really sure why you are expecting to get data back from a save that'll change your page though.  Seems a bit odd.

What type of data are you expecting to receive after a save that wouldn't be in your model?